# Matrix multiplication resulting in different values in MATLAB and NUMPY(?)

Tags: matlab, numpy, matrix-multiplication

Here's the matrix

```
>> x = [2 7 5 9 2; 8 3 1 6 10; 4 7 3 10 1; 6 7 10 1 8;2 8 2 5 9]
```

Matlab gives me

```
>> mtimes(x',x)
ans =

   124   124    94   122   154
   124   220   145   198   179
    94   145   139   101   121
   122   198   101   243   141
   154   179   121   141   250
```

However, the same operation(on same data) in python(numpy) produces different result. I'm unable to understand why?

```
import numpy as np
a = [[2, 7, 5, 9, 2],[8,3,1,6,10],[4,7,3,10,1],[6,7,10,1,8],[2,8,2,5,9]]
x = np.array(a)
print 'A : ',type(x),'\n',x,'\n\n'
# print np.transpose(A)
X = np.multiply(np.transpose(x),x)
print "A'*A",type(X),'\n',X
```

produces

```
A :  <type 'numpy.ndarray'> 
[[ 2  7  5  9  2]
 [ 8  3  1  6 10]
 [ 4  7  3 10  1]
 [ 6  7 10  1  8]
 [ 2  8  2  5  9]] 


A'*A <type 'numpy.ndarray'> 
[[  4  56  20  54   4]
 [ 56   9   7  42  80]
 [ 20   7   9 100   2]
 [ 54  42 100   1  40]
 [  4  80   2  40  81]]
```

[image: Snapshot]

Comment: You must be doing *element-wise* multiplication in numpy. In Matlab, `x.'.*x` gives the same result as you have there. Double check the syntax for *matrix* multiplication.

Comment: @mikkola indeed, the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html) confirms it. You might want to make that an answer. (Matrix multiplication in numpy is done with `dot`)

Comment: Not a duplicate, I think; this is about the `multiply` method, unlike the other question

Comment: @DavidZ I guess. `*` and `multiply` are equivalent. Either way, the spirit of 'make sure you're using the right operation' is maintained and the answer covers both element and matrix multiplication.

Comment: @excaza Correct.  `np.multiply` does the same thing as element-wise multiplication in MATLAB (`.*)`.  In fact, `*` evaluates to `np.multiply` if you look at the official NumPy source.  To perform matrix multiplication, `np.dot` is required and equivalently `*` in MATLAB.

Comment: @excaza  I vote for 'Not Duplicate' ( I did land on the other question but that wasn't so clear )

Comment: The other question is about scalar matrix multiplication, that's a slightly different topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Numpy [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html) states that the operator you apply performs *element-wise* multiplication.

However, [`mtimes`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mtimes.html) in MATLAB does *matrix* multiplication.

To verify, MATLAB syntax for element-wise multiplication produces the same result you see in numpy:

```
disp(x.'.*x)

     4    56    20    54     4
    56     9     7    42    80
    20     7     9   100     2
    54    42   100     1    40
     4    80     2    40    81
```